# Recreate viewController in Navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a certain situation I would like to solve:

I have a `UIViewController` that loads. On a certain condition, I choose to show a new `UIViewController` on top of it in a navigation stack. After that, I want to leave the previous `UIViewController` in the stack, but I want to sort of `release` it, so when the top VC pops to the first one, I would find it not in the condition I left it, but as if it was just pushed.

Nevertheless, I understand that I might just want to push it on top of a 2nd VC, but that would create a mess in the navigation stack and could potentially create a memory leak as this behavior might be looped.

I'm using ARC and building an app for iOS 6 and up.

Comment: What about "resetting" the first viewController in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @MartinR how do you do this then? Any convenient method? I wouldn't really like to recreate all the stuff I have created in the `viewDidLoad` method manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two choices:

1. `viewWillAppear` is called in the first view controller if the second one is popped off
   the navigation stack, so you can reset all state and UI elements of the first view
   controller in that method.
2. Before popping the second view controller, you can use the `setViewControllers:animated:` method of `UINavigationController` to *replace* the first view controller instance with a new instance in the navigation stack.

So it depends on whether you want to keep the first view controller instance and just "reset" it  or if you want a "fresh" instance of the first view controller when coming back
from the second one.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to send Notification from 2nd VC to 1st VC, and tell it to unload a view and then manually load it:

2nd VC:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   postNotificationName:@"unloadVC" object:nil];
}
```

1st VC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                          selector:@selector(unloadVC:) 
                                              name:@"unloadVC" 
                                            object:nil];
}

- (IBAction)unloadVC:(id)sender{
self.view = nil;

[self viewDidLoad];
}
```

The code is not tested though.